# Clicking on a link for the second time the selected list item should be deselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have written code for whenever user clicks on a `li` item it will be selected and when user clicks on the same link again it should be descelected.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").trigger("click");
  jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function() {
    jQuery("#legend li").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#legend li:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.tribe-events-category-5 {
  background-color: #800000;
  border-left: 5px solid #800000;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#legend li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
  <li><span>All</span></li>
  <li class="tribe-events-category-5"><span>Music</span></li>
  <li><span>Dance</span></li>
  <li><span>Festives</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: take a look at jquery hasClass to care for removal.

Comment: can the user select multiple lines ?

Comment: @SoltaniNeji the user cannot select multiple

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").trigger("click");
jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function(){    
    jQuery("#legend li").not(this).removeClass("active");
jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
});
jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not applying any condition for toggling **active** class for you **li**. In order to apply this, Change your

```
jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function(){            
    jQuery("#legend li").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
});
```

to

```js
jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function(){
    if( jQuery("#legend li").hasClass("active") )
    {
      jQuery("#legend li").removeClass("active");
    }
    else{
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

or like @soltani said
use

```
jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
```

instead of my if logic

Comment: not working  not able to display the selected one also

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the current element using `.not()` the use [`toggleClas‌()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass1) on current to add/remove the class

```
jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function () {
    //Remove active class excluding  current element
    jQuery("#legend li").not(this).removeClass("active");

    //Toggle the class
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function() {
    //Remove active class excluding  current element
    jQuery("#legend li").not(this).removeClass("active");

    //Toggle the class
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").trigger("click");
});
```

```css
#legend li:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.tribe-events-category-5 {
  background-color: #800000;
  border-left: 5px solid #800000;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#legend li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
  <li><span>All</span></li>
  <li class="tribe-events-category-5"><span>Music</span></li>
  <li><span>Dance</span></li>
  <li><span>Festives</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
just changed :

```
 jQuery("#legend li").removeClass("active");
 jQuery(this).addClass("active");
```

to :

```
jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").trigger("click");
jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function(){
    jQuery("#legend li").not(this).removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
});
});
```

```css
#legend li:not(.active) {   
opacity: 0.3;
}
.tribe-events-category-5{
background-color: #800000;
border-left: 5px solid #800000;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
color: #fff;
line-height: 1.4em;
padding-left: 5px;
}
#legend li{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
  <li><span>All</span></li>
  <li class="tribe-events-category-5"><span>Music</span></li>
  <li><span>Dance</span></li>
  <li><span>Festives</span></li>
</ul>
```

Edit:
just added this line

```
jQuery("#legend li").not(this).removeClass("active");
```

to prevent the user from selecting multiple

Comment: There was an issue with code if i select all and again if i select dance all is also selected but the opacity of all should change if i select other one

Comment: you mean that you should just select one every time ?

Comment: @user8879490 check now

Comment: check your question now or edit it , you are now demanding different things